# invoke active_record error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to generate a Post model in rails using the following code:

```
rails g model Post url:string, title: string
```

When I execute that line I get the following output:

```
invoke  active_record
Another migration is already named create_posts: /Users/myname/Desktop/folder/my_project/db/migrate/20121212021831_create_posts.rb
```

It seems to be expressing a conflict as though the file already exists in my Model folder - which it does not.

Is this a naming problem?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conflicting migration would be in your db/migrate folder, not app/models.

Your two options are naming your new migration something else or removing the old migration. If you choose to remove the old migration, make sure to roll it back first before deleting it, so that your database schema is correct.

Comment: I had in my project a model named Contact. I renamed it to Office. Now I should create new model with name Contact. So what is the best name for new migration?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can happen when you execute `rails g model post` for multiple times. You can resolve this issue by executing the `rails destroy model post` to remove last generated content.